# can't upload multiple image with use validation mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help guys. My code updates only the first image. When I try to update two more images my code doesn't work.

This my code

```
<?php
include ("config.php");
$id= $_POST['id'];
$judul = $_POST['judul'];
$tanggal = $_POST['tanggal'];
$konten1 = $_POST['konten1'];
$konten2 = $_POST['konten2'];
$konten3 = $_POST['konten3'];
$posisi=$_POST['posisi'];
$posisi2=$_POST['posisi2'];
$tema=$_POST['tema'];
$footer=$_POST['footer'];
$lokasi_file    = $_FILES['banner']['tmp_name'];
$nama_file      = $_FILES['banner']['name'];

$lokasi_foto1   = $_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name'];
$nama_foto1     = $_FILES['foto1']['name'];

$lokasi_foto2   = $_FILES['foto2']['tmp_name'];
$nama_foto2     = $_FILES['foto2']['name'];

$lokasi_logo    = $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'];
$nama_logo      = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
if(isset($_FILES['logo'] ) && ($_FILES['banner']) && $_FILES['banner']['name'] !="" && $_FILES['logo']['name'] !="") {
$hapus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE id='$id'");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($hapus);
$d = 'upload/'.$r['logo'];
$e = 'upload/'.$r['banner'];
unlink ($d);
unlink ($e);
move_uploaded_file($lokasi_logo,"upload/".$nama_logo);
move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file,"upload/".$nama_file);
if ($edit = mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET  banner='$nama_file' , judul='$judul', tanggal='$tanggal', posisi='$posisi',konten1='$konten1', konten2='$konten2', konten3='$konten3', tema='$tema' ,posisi2 = '$posisi2', footer='$footer' , logo='$nama_logo' WHERE id='$id'")){
    header("Location: newsletter.php");
    exit();
}
die ("Terdapat kesalahan : ". mysql_error($konek));
}

if ($edit = mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET judul='$judul', tanggal='$tanggal', posisi='$posisi',konten1='$konten1', konten2='$konten2', konten3='$konten3' , tema='$tema' ,posisi2 = '$posisi2', footer='$footer'  WHERE id='$id'")){
    header("Location: newsletter.php");
    exit();
}
die ("Terdapat kesalahan : ". mysql_error($konek));

?>
```

So if I try to update the banner and the logo, my code just updates the banner. The Logo is not updated. If anyone can help , I will be happy :)

EDIT :
The problem on this my code is on after `if (isset)` I am confuse how to use multiple isset with use that

Answer (score 0):

You're using `exit()`, meaning that when the banner is uploaded, the script will terminate. Unless there's more code to this, there's no need to use exit()

[Source: PHP exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

Comment: Thank's for attention guys , but i know if I am using exit() , it will terminate script . But I am put exit() at the end of the script , if I am disabling it , nothing happen , The logo still not update , just The banner will update